# What is an effective way to erase thin lines, for example, notebook ones?

Tags: blur

What is an effective way to erase thin lines, for example, notebook ones?
[image: Notebook sheet on which I need to erase the lines.]

Comment: ermm.. don't use notebook paper? Kinda need to see an example if you're referring to something that happens to be on notebook paper, even if it's just a small cropped area.

Comment: @Scott This question is a part of computer-vision task. Line removal is necessary) Imagine that we know coordinates of line and the task is to erase it. 
Is it worth clarifying the issue?

Comment: Try using existing ML tools that remove parts of images by filling in the background. However given the pretty terrible lighting and such of this photo even those might not do a great job.

Comment: This question is not really on topic for graphicdesign.se as is

Comment: @ZachSaucier Mathematicians sent me here)

Comment: Graphic Designers don't use math to determine line coordinates... they simply adjust the image as a whole.

Comment: If you're seeking a formulaic, or mathematical system, to achieve this, then GD.SE is *absolutely* not the right Stack.  It would be far more related to Computer Science or Math than it is to graphic design.

Comment: Median filtering fades thin lines. But you have not at all defined what else there's is in the image - maybe something between and on those thin lines.? Something, which should stay intact, no matter just the shown lines fade away?

Comment: @user287001 Along with the lines, we can also erase the text. I will then look for a way to restore it)

Comment: What you want to keep - what prevents clearing the whole area which seems to have the color of the paper? BTW you can try Filter > Noise > Median in Photoshop. It blurs most of the text and removes only thinnest lines from it.. Nothing restores the text from that mess.